# Check if in celery task

Tags: python, flask, celery, celery-task

How to check that a function in executed by [celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/#minimal-example)?

```
def notification():
   # in_celery() returns True if called from celery_test(), 
   #                     False if called from not_celery_test()
   if in_celery():
      # Send mail directly without creation of additional celery subtask
      ...
   else:
      # Send mail with creation of celery task
      ...

@celery.task()
def celery_test():
    notification()

def not_celery_test():
    notification()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by using `celery.current_task`. Here is the code to be used by the task:

```
def notification():
    from celery import current_task
    if not current_task:
        print "directly called"
    elif current_task.request.id is None:
        print "called synchronously"
    else:
        print "dispatched"

@app.task
def notify():
    notification()
```

This is code you can run to exercise the above:

```
        from core.tasks import notify, notification
        print "DIRECT"
        notification()
        print "NOT DISPATCHED"
        notify()
        print "DISPATCHED"
        notify.delay().get()
```

My task code in the first snippet was in a module named `core.tasks`. And I shoved the code in the last snippet in a custom Django management command. This tests 3 cases:

- Calling `notification` directly.
- Calling `notification` through a task executed synchronously. That is, this task is not dispatched through Celery to a worker. The code of the task executes in the same process that calls `notify`.
- Calling `notification` through a task run by a worker. The code of the task executes in a different process from the process that started it.

The output was:

```
NOT DISPATCHED
called synchronously
DISPATCHED
DIRECT
directly called
```

There is no line from the `print` in the task on the output after `DISPATCHED` because that line ends up in the worker log:

```
[2015-12-17 07:23:57,527: WARNING/Worker-4] dispatched
```

**Important note**: I initially was using `if current_task is None` in the first test but it did not work. I checked and rechecked. Somehow Celery sets `current_task` to an object which looks like `None` (if you use `repr` on it, you get `None`) but is not `None`. Unsure what is going on there. Using `if not current_task` works.

Also, I've tested the code above in a Django application but I've not used it in production. There may be gotchas I don't know.

Comment: I think that in order for `current_task` to be populated, you need to specify `bind=True` in your @app decorator:
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks